# Django annotate with related_name from A->C where A->B and B->C where '->' is reverse relationship

Tags: django, django-annotate

I searched a lot on internet but could not find a similar question.

I have 3 models : `Domain`, `Topic`, `Post`
Each `Domain` can have many `Topics` and each `Topic` can have many `Posts`.

`Topic` has a `foreign key` to `Domain` and `Post` has a `foreign key` to `Topic`.

So I can include `count of Posts` in `Topic` by `annotate(Count('posts'))`
and I can include `count of Topics` in `Board` by `annotate(Count('topics'))`

Is there any way to include `count of Posts` in `Board` by `annotate` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use double underscores (`__`) to look through a relation:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Domain.objects.annotate(
    num_posts=Count('topics__posts')
)
```

if you combine this with counting the number of `Topic`s, you will need to add [**`distinct=True`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Count.distinct) to the `Count` of the `Topic`s, since this will make two `JOIN`s, and the `JOIN` on `Post`s will act as a "*multiplier*":

```
from django.db.models import Count

Domain.objects.annotate(
    num_posts=Count('topics__posts'),
    num_topics=Count('topics', distinct=True)
)
```

This will result in a query like:

```
SELECT domain.*
       COUNT(post.id) AS num_posts
       COUNT(DISTINCT topic.id) AS num_topics
FROM domain
LEFT OUTER JOIN topic ON topic.domain_id = domain.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN post ON post.topic_id = topic.id
GROUP BY domain.id
```

If you would have omitted the `distinct=True`, the same topic would be counted *multiple* times (exactly the same number of times as the number of posts related to that topic), and thus `num_topics` should then be the same as `num_posts`. By using `DISTINCT` we count the number of *unique* topics in each group.

Comment: I understand the first part and my query is resolved...however can you explain what you meant in second part (two JOINs)...?

Comment: @Yusuf: it will query with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM domain LEFT OUTER JOIN topic ON topic.domain_id = domain.id LEFT OUT JOIN post ON post.topic_id = topic.id GROUP BY domain.id`. So if we count `topic`s, it will not count *unique* topics, but for each post count the same topic (so multiple times). To prevent that, we count unique topics.

Comment: so ```distinct=True``` should come for num_posts, right ?

Comment: @Ysuf: it does not matter in what order you define the `count`s, but you should count *distinct* topics, since that is where the "duplication" will happen.

Comment: The SQL query you mentioned above will be generated for num_posts and for num_topics it will be like : ```select count(*) from domain inner join topic on domain.id=topic.domain.id```

Comment: @Yusuf: but it will not make two separate count queries if you annotate both in the same `.annotate(..)` clause.

Comment: Oh! thanks ..now I got it..why duplication will happen

Comment: I have another query- should i create another question or you can answer here only - If I want to annotate new column for ```domain``` like ```last_updated_post``` where it will store the last updated ```post```, how to write ```annotate``` statement for this - MW ```post``` has one field ```updated_on``` (DateTimeField)   - Something like ```domain.objects.annotate(postt='topics__posts'.order_by('-updated_on').first())```

Comment: @Yusuf: you can add as extra annotation `last_updated_post=Max('topics__posts__updated_on')`.

Comment: @Yusuf: for the latest post itself, however that will require extra joining, and might be better done in two steps. Probably worth writing an new question.

Comment: I am writing another question!

Comment: The link to new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61291587/django-annotate-with-field-of-related-name-of-related-name