# Django annotate with 'field' of 'related_name' of 'related_name'

Tags: django, django-annotate

I have three models : `Domain` `Topic` `Post`

`Topic` has a `foreign key` to `Domain` and `Post` has a `foreign key` to `Topic`.

`Post` has a field `updated_on`.

I want to annotate `last_updated` field in `Domain` queryset which would contain the **latest** post object from `Post` .

Edit 1: Added models definition:

```
class Board(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Topic(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='topics', null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='topics', null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)    
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

class Post(models.Model):
    message = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='posts', null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='posts', null=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Comment: Can you add your models?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu models added..

Comment: I don't need just the latest post's date but the entire post object or post object id but based on updated_on field